# jquery:2 ways of accessing top document from iframe?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a main document with an IFRAME tag.
From inside de IFRAME I'm accesing a DIV ID="results" located in the main document.

I can succesfully reach the DIV this way:

var message = $(**document**, parent.window.document).contents().find('#results').html();

BUT firstly I tried next one, but didn't work:

var message = $(parent.window.document).contents().find('#results').html();

Why the last one isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1:

```
By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root.
```

In the first case, you are searching for the `document` in the context of the parent document, so you find the right document object. In the second (non-working) case, you are searching for the parent document in the context of the IFRAME's document: you won't find anything because the parent document doesn't really exist in that context.